# How do I dinamically import the content of this Google sheet into a new sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to import the content of the following sheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O39L_z1lJUyW-AXCYyVH_MZ9eGWMbQ4_kHNDPW862iw/edit?usp=sharing into an empty sheet. This needs to be done in a way that if new data gets added in the parent sheet, it is automatically copied in the new one. I shpuld also have the option to modify a formula in the "new" sheet only.

Comment: Use IMPORTRANGE formula. 
In your case to import "Calendar" sheet IMPORTRANGE("1O39L_z1lJUyW-AXCYyVH_MZ9eGWMbQ4_kHNDPW862iw", "Calendar!A:X")

Comment: Reference: [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import to a different **spreadsheet**, use [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en), as mentioned by [Oleg_S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64855595/how-do-i-dinamically-import-the-content-of-this-google-sheet-into-a-new-sheet#comment114665815_64855595):

```
=IMPORTRANGE("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID", "Calendar!A:X")
```

If you want to import to another **sheet** in the same spreadsheet, you have other options at your disposal:

- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Calendar!A:X)
```

- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en&ref_topic=3105411):

```
=QUERY(Calendar!A:X)
```

#### Note:

- Please notice that, if you want the target sheet to get automatically updated when the source data is modified, you will not be able to modify the data in the target sheet directly.